# python class method that receives an object of its class

Tags: python, class-method

I want to create a Square class that has method to calculate the distance from another Square. Here is how I have defined it:

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, _x: int, _y: int):
        self.x = _x
        self.y = _y

    def distance(self, _other_square: Square) -> int:
        pass
```

The `_other_square` is an object of type `Square`.
This gives me an Unresolved reference 'Square' error.

Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: @TomKarzes This seems to solve the issue: from __future__ import annotations
Thanks

Comment: BTW, please do not post images of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function definition to this:

```
def distance(self, _other_square: 'Square') -> int:
        pass
```

The type hint is now a `str` instance which will be resolved after the module has been loaded, and therefore the `Square` type is defined. [See here for all details.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)

Comment: This clearly solves my issue. Thanks